# Deploy mock-server instance for only staging/development environments

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mockserver, sidecar

I need to implement a mock server whose instance needs to be deployed on **non-production environments**. I am using docker image  [mockserver/mockserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/mockserver/mockserver)

**To Clarify I'll explain the scenario here:** Our app will be using a 3rd part API which is not available in sandbox environment and for that we need to mock the apis for staging. This mocked server's instance wil only run for staging and development environment.

I need to deploy this using [kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) only for `staging` and `development` environment and not for the `production` one.

There are couple of solutions in my mind but not sure which is better.

1. Deploy a `separate instance` of this mock-server(aside from main app container) only for non-production environments.
2. Or deploy this mock-server as as `sidecar` next to main container. (But not sure how this sidecar can be deployed only for staging and development only)

Please suggest which approach is better and why and is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: This is way to broad with a lack of any kind of example

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I have edited the question, I hope it gives more clarity.

Comment: IMO it should be its own k8s service and deployment.